# Passing a Tuple or Triple as parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tuples, arguments

I have a function in Kotlin that is something like this:

```kotlin
fun getSlots(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    // some magic stuff, for example let's just print it
    print("$year-$month-$day")
}
```

And I have another function that returns a `Triple`:

```kotlin
fun myMagicFunction(): Triple<Int, Int, Int> {
    return Triple(2020, 1, 1)
}
```

I would like to call to the first function `getSlots`, using the return value of the second function `myMagicFunction`, without having to extract the members from the triple and pass them one by one. Something that in Python for example is possible by doing `func(*args)`, but I don't know if it is possible in Kotlin.

Is it possible in Kotlin or do I have to go the slow way with this situation? Assume that modifying the previous two functions to return something else is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not (yet?) supported by Kotlin. Technically speaking it should be doable as we have destructing declarations in Kotlin and they are type-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any simple way (hopefully it will be available some day in kotlin).
However you can write some helper infix function like this:

```
infix fun  <T, U, S, V> KFunction3<T, U, S, V>.callWith(arguments: Triple<T, U, S>) : V = this.call(*arguments.toList().toTypedArray())
```

and then just simply call it:

```
::getSlots callWith myMagicFunction()
```

Of course you can add another one for Pair:

```
infix fun  <T, U, V> KFunction2<T, U, V>.callWith(arguments: Pair<T, U>) : V = this.call(*arguments.toList().toTypedArray())
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @broot we have better solution:

```
infix fun  <T, U, S, V> ((T, U, S) -> V).callWith(arguments: Triple<T, U, S>) : V = this(arguments.first, arguments.second, arguments.third)
```

Comment: I suggest replacing `KFunction` with function type. Then destructure items manually. First, I think `KFunction` works only on JVM target. Second, original solution initially creates a list, then converts it to array, it creates another copy of that array and then passes it to reflection. We can do it almost directly and multiplatform with this code: `infix fun  <T, U, S, V> ((T, U, S) -> V).callWith(arguments: Triple<T, U, S>) : V = this(arguments.first, arguments.second, arguments.third)`.

Comment: Note that usage of Reflection API has a performance penalty

Comment: Also, alternatively we can create `operator fun invoke` and then the resulting code becomes: `(::getSlots)(myMagicFunction())`.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin also has a spread operator (`func(*args)`), but currently it works only if the argument of `func` is declared as `vararg` (to avoid runtime exception if the size of `args` is not the same as `func` arity).

Just add one more code line with destructing declaration:

```kotlin
val (year, month, day) = myMagicFunction()
getSlots(year, month, day)
```